# Parsing double with comma as decimal separator

Tags: java, number-formatting

I get inputs from  user and read it line by line.Then I'm using split method to tokenize the inputs. Like this:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
String input1=input.nextLine();
String[] tokens=input1.split(" ");
method1(Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]),Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]));
```

Here is `method1`:

```
 public static void method1 (double a, double b) {
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
 }
```

When I declare 3.5 and 5.3 output;

```
   3.5
   5.3
```

Here there is no problem but if I declare 3,5 and 5,3 my code giving error in below;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3,5"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you think would happen when you try to parse `42,42` as double?

Comment: How is 3,5 a double? Obviously it will throw `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: To people downvoting: `42,7` with a comma is a widely-accepted number for mat in some cultures.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) you can do something like this:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
double myNumber = f.parse("3,5").doubleValue();
```

Now you can pass `myNumber` to the method that accepts `double` value.

When using [`Locale.FRANCE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#FRANCE), you tell Java that you write `double` numbers with `,` instead of `.`.

Comment: Now the OP would need to post another question for not being to parse `3.5` :)

Comment: You should have instead suggested replacing `,` with `.` :)

Comment: also i musn't use expections

Comment: @Abraam Avoidance of exceptions shows the unwillingness to use Java standard practices. If you don't want an exception to propagate, catch and handle it.

Comment: @hexafraction That's not of my willing or unwilling. I said that I musn't use ! Think before answer

Comment: @Abraam Then why would you have *any* other reason not to use exceptions? I don't see logic I can follow with why you must not use exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DecimalFormat` like this:

```
DecimanFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance());
Double returnValue = Double.valueOf(df.format(input1));
```

So `DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance()` will get the default locale and its correct symbols.

Read More about [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

what i guess is : 
your input via scaner is

```
3.5 5.3
```

and you have applied

```
String[] tokens=input1.split(" ");
```

so it has divided your strings in to substrings ie 3.5 and 5.3
if you give your input as

```
3.5,5.3
```

It will be a success and it will compile without an error..

**in your case**

```
input 3,5 5,3
```

it you just need to put a "," in split method like :

```
String[] tokens=input1.split(",");
```

and it will work with output as ....

3

5 5

3